# closed loop integral when $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I'm just learning about green's formula and im wondering about what happens when $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$. Suppose that we're trying to calculate the closed loop integral:

$\gamma: (2, 0) \to (-1,1) \to (0, -2) \to (1, 2) \to (-2, -1) \to (2, 0)$ (i.e. a star :D)

$P(x,y)=  \frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}$
$Q(x,y)=  \frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$

$\int_\gamma Pdx + Qdy$

Since its a closed loop I figured I could try to calculate this expression using Green's formula, however given that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ we just integrate over $0$, which should the answer 0. Yet the corrct answer is $4\pi$.

Comment: The Green formula is applicable when the path of integration is the (oriented) boundary of a domain $\mathcal{D}$ and both $P$ and $Q$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathcal{D}$. (And more generally, the formula kind of applies - with due modification - if $\gamma$ can be continuously deformed into a point, and both $P$ and $Q$ are continuously differentiable on the region swept by this deformation.) In your case, $\gamma$ winds the singularity of $P$ and $Q$, hence the Green formula does not apply.

Comment: Alright, but how do you solve this problem if Greens formula doesn't apply? Do you have to painstakingly calculate the line integral directly?

Comment: I would be surprised if the textbook you are reading is not demonstrating the relevant technique. As GReyes illustrated, the trick in this problem is that you can replace $\gamma$ by a much simpler path. More precisely, if $\gamma$ can be continuously deformed, without crossing the singularities of $P$ and $Q$ (in this case, the origin), to another curve, then the value of the line integral remains the same under the deformation. In this case, $\gamma$ can be deformed into the circular path, centered at the origin $0$, that winds the origin twice in the counter-clockwise direction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a "hole" around the origin, and orient it clockwise. Then, Green's formula applies to the combined contour. Since you have $Q_x=P_y$, the double integral in the punctured region will be zero, and the conclusion is that your integral is equal to
$$
\oint_C Pdx+Qdy,
$$
where $C$ is a positively oriented circle of small radius $\epsilon$ around the origin, such that the circle is contained in your star (you go around the circle twice). Then you have to parametrize the circle, but the computation will be simple because on the circle, $x^2+y^2=\epsilon^2$. Of course your result will not depend on $\epsilon$.